# Integral problem with perfect square in denominator, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(1-\beta z^{-1})^2}\,dz$

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve this problem, but I failed to solve it several times.
It is very difficult for me.

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(1-\beta z^{-1})^2}\,dz$$

Comment: How does the integrand behave for $\lvert z\rvert\to\infty$?

Comment: @DanielFischer will it be 1? I think that denominator of z make beta multiply inverse of z be zero.

Comment: Indeed. So what follows for the integral?

Comment: @DanielFischer I think that it will be needed to substitute (1-bz^(-1)) to something that which makes it solve easily

Comment: What about $\int_{-\infty}^\infty 1\,dx$?

Comment: @DanielFischer it will be positive infinite:D

Comment: And what does that indicate about your integral here?

Comment: @DanielFischer can't it be expressed as an exact number? or it is not able to compute my intergral here

Comment: The integral doesn't exist. If $\beta$ is real, we can assign the value $+\infty$ to it, but if $\beta$ is a non-real complex number, not even that.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for commenting for 2 days!